# Python tkinter: pausing a loop until key pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a piece of code with tkinter like following:

```
def function_call():
    x = 5;
    for _ in range (10):
        ...
        ...
        ...
        //pause here until F9 is pressed
        


root = tk.Tk()
...
...
...
root.bind('<F1>', lambda event: function_call()) //Using F1 to invoke call
```

Does anyone know how to pause the loop, until F9 is pressed? Please help.

Comment: Do you mean that the code pauses at the end of each iteration and proceeds after pressing F9 in each iteration?

Comment: yep, exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tkinter has a function `.wait_variable(var)` to pause the application and wait for tkinter `var` to be updated.  So you can bind key `<F9>` to update the tkinter variable to stop the waiting:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def function_call(event=None):
    for i in range(10):
        print('Hello', i)
        # wait for pause_var to be updated
        root.wait_variable(pause_var)
    print('done')

root = tk.Tk()
# tkinter variable for .wait_variable()
pause_var = tk.StringVar()
root.bind('<F1>', function_call)
# press <F9> to update the tkinter variable
root.bind('<F9>', lambda e: pause_var.set(1))
root.mainloop()
```

Note that if the job inside the for loop is time-consuming, then better to run `function_call()` in a child thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you can build on. It will wait until "F9" key is pressed, and when pressed it will change text.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

state = 'startup'


def loop():
    if state == 'startup':
        Label(text="The Game is starting now!").grid(row=0, column=0)
    elif state == 'running':
        Label(text="The Game is running now!").grid(row=0, column=0)

    root.after(20, loop)


def key(event):
    global state
    if state == 'startup':
        state = 'running'


root.bind('<Key-F9>', key)
root.after(20, loop)
root.mainloop()
```